# Why does Eclipse launch so slowly on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, java, eclipse

I noticed sometime after updating to Yosemite that Eclipse now launches very slowly. It takes 30 seconds to a minute to get to the startup splash screen, and after that it spends a minute or two initializing itself before the IDE comes up.

I've seen this issue even after updating Eclipse. I went from Luna to Mars to Mars.1 and it is still a problem. I have a number of perspectives installed (Java, C/C++, Python, and JS), but these were installed and working admirably before the issue started.

Tried a few things mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316265/how-can-you-speed-up-eclipse

- Increasing the amount of memory for the launcher and application in eclipse.ini (ctrl-click application -> Show Package Contents)
- Updated Eclipse and all plugins

I noticed immediately after changing eclipse.ini, Eclipse opens a lot faster. On subsequent launches it is slow again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.

I inspected the logs and noticed the PyDev plugin was searching for a Python 2.5 interpreter (which had been installed on previous OS X installations). After I removed the Python 2.5 interpreter from PyDev's list of configured interpreters, the issue vanished.